# What is -js-display: flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

Was searching a bit to see if there was any parsers to handle flexbox for older versions of IE and stumbled upon [this bad boy](https://github.com/7rulnik/postcss-flexibility). My question isn't in regards to backwards compatibility of flex it is simply what does this syntax mean/do:

```
-js-display: flex;
```

Comment: It's vendor prefix syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Answer (score 1):

That is a non-standard property that is only intended to work with the [Flexibility Polyfill script](https://github.com/10up/flexibility), which emulates Flexbox support for older IE. The link you provided is a plugin for PostCSS that automatically adds that bit of custom syntax—there is a link to the Flexbility polyfill from the page you linked to as well.